# Trying to pass multilevel object to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web form in which the user checks a box and it gets added to a post request that some other page will handle.  Currently I am doing the following, and it just seems wrong.

```
data = "";
$.each($('.itemActivate'),function(){

   if ($(this).is(':checked')){
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       var title = $('#'+id+"_title").val();
       var qty = $('#'+id+"_qty").val();
       var cost = $('#'+id+"_cost").val();
       var setup = $('#'+id+"_setup").val();
       var msrp = $('#'+id+"_msrp").val();
       var code = id;

       data += "codes[]="+code+"&";
       data += "titles[]="+title+"&";
       data += "qty[]="+qty+"&";
       data += "cost[]="+cost+"&";
       data += "setup[]="+setup+"&";
       data += "msrp[]="+msrp+"&";
   }
});

$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"quotePreview.php",
   data:data,
   success: function(result){ // blah }
```

I assume it would be better to send it as an object as opposed to a long list of get variables.  something like this:

```
var a = 1;
$.each($('.itemActivate'),function(){
   if ($(this).is(':checked')){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var title = $('#'+id+"_title").val();
     var qty = $('#'+id+"_qty").val();
     var cost = $('#'+id+"_cost").val();
     var setup = $('#'+id+"_setup").val();
     var msrp = $('#'+id+"_msrp").val();
     var code = id;

     data = { a : {'code' : code,'title' : title}...//etc};
     a++;
  }
});

$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"quotePreview.php",
   data:data,
   success: function(result){ // blah }
```

Is my asssumption correct?  What is the correct way to build the data object to send?

Comment: You're using JQuery. Never build your own query string, use https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 2):

your `data` will be overwritten everytime the iteration runs. In the end there will only be a single object. change

```
data = { a : {'code' : code,'title' : title}...//etc};
```

to

```
data[a] = {'code' : code,'title' : title}...//etc};
```

and change `var data =""` to `const data = {}`

Comment: Where does he ever assign `a = ""` ??

Comment: @MattOestreich yep you're right thats a typo. I meant `data` of course :) fixed that

Comment: @MattOestreich and to answer that other question: he does before the second code block. But both of us know whats the real reason for the downvote xD

Comment: Your creating an object with the keys of 1, 2, 3 etc.. which is exactly what ARRAYS are meant for....

Answer (score 0):

initialize the array data `var data = []` before the foreach loop and use `Array.push()` to add you data items inside the foreach loop.

```js
 
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e){
 e.preventDefault();

var data = [];
$.each($('.checkbox'),function(){
   if ($(this).is(':checked')){

     var id = $(this).attr('name');

     data.push({'id' : id});
   }
 
});

console.log(data);
}
```

```html
 <form id="form">
  <label for="cb1">Checkbox 1</label>
  <input id="cb2" type="checkbox" name="1" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <label for="cb2">Checkbox 2</label>
  <input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="2" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <label for="cb3">Checkbox 3</label>
  <input id="cb3" type="checkbox" name="3" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <label for="cb4">Checkbox 4</label>
  <input id="cb4" type="checkbox" name="4" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <label for="cb5">Checkbox 5</label>
  <input id="cb5" type="checkbox" name="5" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <label for="cb6">Checkbox 6</label>
  <input id="cb6" type="checkbox" name="6" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <label for="cb7">Checkbox 7</label>
  <input id="cb7" type="checkbox" name="7" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <label for="cb8">Checkbox 8</label>
  <input id="cb8" type="checkbox" name="8" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <label for="cb9">Checkbox 9</label>
  <input id="cb9" type="checkbox" name="9" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <label for="cb10">Checkbox 10</label>
  <input id="cb10" type="checkbox" name="10" class="checkbox"><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="">
 </form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```